# MiKTeX updates packages only partially

Tags: miktex, console

When I requested recently MiKTeX console to update my installation (portable version on Win10) I noticed that not all packages that have been updated in the package database are recognized to be updated. Latest examples are babel, fira, l3kernel. These are not experimental packages, are they? Can somebody confirm that observation?

Comment: In the old days MikTeX would give certain system infrastructure packages preferential treatment which meant that one had to run the updater twice to get a fully updated system. I haven't seen that behaviour lately, but I don't know if it is still there. With a normal install there is always the issue of User v Admin mode, but I'm not sure if that is relevant for a portable install. How exactly do you know the packages were supposed to be updated but aren't? Do you maybe have local files not controlled by this MikTeX that have precedence over MikTeX-installed files?

Comment: MikTeX package repository is not updated everyday, therefore the most recent MikTeX update could not contain the most recent CTAN version of last updated packages. You can see at miktex.org last update date, if desired packages where updated on CTAN later, you'll have to wait for next MikTeX update or install the package yourself..

Comment: @moewe. I have no local files. I checked the updates via the 'Packages' dialog in MikTeX console. Also after synchronizing the local package database. In this case, the column 'Packaged on' contains dates that is newer the one in column 'Installed on'. Yes, I noticed that during the last 15 days or so I got only binary files as updates. But I'm convinced that I should have got the others meanwhile as well.

Comment: I can confirm a similar odd set of dates i.e. babel in my case installed last November is not confirmed as updated to match 04/04 package taking a simple example Polyglossia is shown but not confirmed as 06/04/19 the folder is the date I first installed and ALL the contents are now a year old as dated 07/04/18 thus the update was not triggered otherwise I would have accepted

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Is that issue worth to be added to the MiKTeX bug tracker?

Comment: Sorting the full list by packaged on date I now see a very high number of packages are lagging behind, thanks for the heads up. I too am using portable, so we need confirmation from a non portable user. in the mean time I will download a fresh portable install ! I guess it is unexpected behaviour some update but others don't (thus a bug) however we may have overlooked some update setting to say give me latest in ALL cases.

Comment: @KJO: Thanks a lot. Please let me know whether a fresh install of the portable has solved the issue.

Comment: I am currently running MiKTeX so for other reasons opted to uninstall the older packages and forcibly reinstall those I thought essential letting any others reload on the fly (saves some needed disk space as am near the USB limit) the current portable from site is one I had earlier but not used (is not 2.9.7 yet) so will possibly wait for next version to do full overwrite

Comment: @KJO I'm running a non-portable multi-user install of MikTeX and have not yet noticed any packages lagging behind. A quick look at the list of packages shows that those all packages installed on my machine updated correctly (at least for the past two weeks or so, didn't go back any further, but `babel`, `l3kernel` and `fira` mentioned in the question are fine.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks that was tfran's suspicion that it may be confined to portable users but I see no obvious reason why that would happen since some update and others don't with currently no obvious rhyme or reason unless there was some other common cause such as a bad hair day

Comment: Did a replacement of portable (it is not a new machine so not a "clean" test) but still seeing similar behaviour a style package (textpos) added on the fly 15th was updated 17th and not flagged as available update